# NameID Value based on Identity Provider/Output Claim Present

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am working on connecting a SAML application to Azure AD B2C and following this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?wt.mc_id=AID2409697_QSG_SCL_499626&ocid=AID2409697_QSG_SCL_499626&tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy

I have this working for local and Facebook accounts. I need to change the returned "NameID" value to the email address of the user. Local account/auth and Facebook account/auth returns the user email address in a different Output claim and I am having issues getting them both to work concurrently (can only do one or the other).

Here is my RelyingParty definition for the custom policy (works for returning the email address for local accounts in the NameID value):

```
<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="userPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="objectId"/>
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="userPrincipalName" ExcludeAsClaim="false"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
```

Idea above is mapping the signInNames.emailAddress to userPrincipalName and then returning userPrincipalName as the NameID.

The OutputClaim "email" is the one that the Facebook identity provider returns the user email address in. If I add "PartnerClaimType="userPrincipalName" to the email OutputClaim and remove it from the "signInNames.emailAddress" OutputClaim...it works for returning the email address as NameID of the user who uses Facebook Identity, but then breaks it for local auth.

Is there a way to detect which OutputClaim is set and map that value into userPrincipalName (or any other claim, not glued to userPrincipalName) and then return it as NameID. Or any other method to accomplish this (such as detecting which identityProvider is used and then setting userPrinicpalName based on that provider)?

Answer (score 0):

Copy email to userprincipalname. This way UPN always satisfies the requirement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/general-transformations#copyclaim